# Almost every where divergent Fourier series

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Does there exist any ***continuous*** function $f:[\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb{C}$  whose Fourier series $\sum \hat{f}(n)e^{int}$ is almost every where divergent?

Comment: No -- this is Carleson's solution of Luzin's conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem